# Why count of an iterable returns 1?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the model

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class WebsiteUser {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String name;
private String email;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

This is the user repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<WebsiteUser, Long> {
List<WebsiteUser> findByName(@RequestParam("name") String name);
}
```

This is my DataLoader:

```
@Component
```

public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

```
private static final Logger log = LogManager.getFormatterLogger(DataLoader.class);

private final UserRepository userRepository;

public DataLoader(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    Iterable<WebsiteUser> data = userRepository.findAll();

    long count = Stream.of(data).count();
    log.info("counted:" + count);
    log.info("data:" + data);

}
}
```

The log returns following values:

> counted:1

> data:[]

I do not understand this return values. The [] is empty and should return 0 and not 1. Can you please explain why is this so? And how can I get 0 instead of 1?

Comment: to get the exact size of the iterable: long count = data.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown(); This returns: count: 0

Answer (score 0):

You have no data.

`Stream.of(data)` makes a stream of iterables. THis stream contains 1 item (`data`), the empty iterable, and will then dutifully go: Yup. 1 empty stream. Count is 1.

Generally you should let collections turn themselves into streams- whatever findAll returns, it's more specific than Iterable, and what it is probably has a stream() method. If it does not, you should upgrade that dependency.